Is drawing characters for role playing permissible?
As-salamu alaykum, the title says itself but I want to clarify what I mean by this. I wanted to buy myself a drawing tablet and since our friends like to do roleplaying, mostly Dungeons and Dragons roleplay. They drew how their characters looked for that session. So I was thinking about it, but drawing animate beings is haram. And I have been searching on this on the internet and from my view I got mixed results.
Some say its permissible, some say its not, some say its permissible under these circumstances (avoiding to draw the face, eyes, nose etc.). So I came here to ask:
Is digital drawing characters, for the purposes of this roleplay permissible or not?

Drawing anything that imitates a soulful being is prohibited, based on the hadith

Abdullah ibn Umar (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Messenger
of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “Those who
make images will be punished on the Day of Resurrection, and it will
be said to them: `Bring to life that which you have created.’”
(Narrated by Al-Bukhari, 5607 and Muslim, 2108)

However, if the art piece excludes a part like nose, or eyes which makes it look lifeless then it is permissible, because it is not a imitation of the soulful being. Instead, one can draw pictures like nature, like trees, and mountains that have no soul in it. If it has animal, or a human being that is a imitation of the creation then it is prohibited.
